# how to consol.log() or view my database data through my javascript file

Tags: javascript, datagrip

Searched in so many places, and i know the answer is really simple but i'm very dumb; i need some help. :

Step 1. I have made a database in Datagrip with all the data.
Step 2. In Visual Studios Code I have a client (contains a html file, router, css file, as well as a clupages.js file) and a server folder.
In the server folder I have a file called server.js (takes care of server connection) , api-register(connects rest api:s to web server and database), and another folder called api and in the api folder I have a file called club.js()

Step 3. in the clubpages I have export default async function that makes it possible to see it on the server website.

My question is  how can i just check if it is really imports the data from the datagrip? Is there a function in Visual Studio Code where i can see it? How can i see if my code is accessing the database data?

tried to console log in both the erver side, in the clupages js file, didn't type out anything.

```
    server.js 

import express from 'express'
import mysql from 'mysql'
import session from 'express-session'
import { promisify } from 'util'
// rest apis
import apiRegister from './api-register.js'

const server = express()
const port = 3000

// Express now includes a built-in JSON body parser
server.use(express.json())

// Configure Express to use sessions
server.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard_cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))

// Configure MySQL connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  
host: 'number',
port: 'number',
user: 'user',
password: 'password',
database: 'databaseName'



})

// Promisify the query method
db.query = promisify(db.query).bind(db);

db.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', err)
    return
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL database')

  // serve static client directory
  server.use(express.static("../client"));

  // connect to API:s
  apiRegister(server, db)

  // Start the server
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })

})
```

```
import club from "./api/club.js";


export default function (server, db) {
  // connect rest api:s to web server and database
  club (server, db)

}
```

```
export default function (server, db) {
  server.get('/api/club', async (req, res) => {
    const club = await db.query("SELECT * FROM club ")
    res.json(club)
  })

  server.post('/api/club', async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.name.trim().length > 0) {
      const result = await db.query("INSERT INTO club(name, description, admin_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [req.body.name, req.body.description, req.body.admin_id ])
      result.clubAdded = true
      res.json(result)
      console.log("Result - ", result);
    } else {
      res.status(401)
      res.json({ clubAdded: false })
    }
  })

  server.put('/api/club/:id', (req, res) => {
  })

  server.delete('/api/club/:id', (req, res) => {
  })

}
```

```
export default async function clubpages() {
  const clubData = await getclubs();
  console.log(clubData);

  return `
  <h1>Booklist</h1>
  ${createBooksTable(clubData)}
  `;
}

async function getclubs() {
  const response = await fetch("/api/club")
  const data = await response.json()
  return data;
}
```

Comment: Presumably you'd edit your database to contain something you know can only exist there, and see that appearing in your app. However, "tried to console log in both the erver side, in the clupages js file, didn't type out anything." sounds like you have some other bug here, which is impossible to debug since you're not showing us any code.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have edited my post. i'm sorry that i was not clearer. would this be more helpful in helping me solve my problem?

Comment: Right, so if you add `console.log("HEJSAN!", club)` right before `res.json(club)` in the `/api/club` handler? Presumably something shows up on your Node.js server's console then every time you access that via the frontend? If not, then that's not happening on the frontend side, and you'd need to figure out why (e.g. with the network inspector in your browser).

Comment: thank you, now i can at final see that it receives the data from the database. 
Last question, how do i get the data to be printed on the "website"? What should i think about/how should i go about it?

Comment: That would depend on how you're calling that `clubpages` function in the client code. By the looks of it, `document.body.innerHTML += await clubpages();` should make _something_ show up...

Comment: thank you for your help, i really appreciate it